# Ajax PHP Call not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried to run the code below but it doesn't work, and I tried everything I remember and couldn't get to work.

AJAX Call

```
var status = $(this).prop("checked");
var room_id = id;
$.post('maintenanceControl.php', {action: status, id: room_id});
```

PHP Script

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if ($action) {
        return manageMaintenance($id, true);
    } else {
        return manageMaintenance($id, false);
    }
}

function manageMaintenance($room_id, $status)
{
    $jsonString = file_get_contents('status.json');
    $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    foreach ($data['rooms'] as $key => $entry) {
        if ($key == $room_id) {
            $data[$key]['maintenance'] = $status;
        }
    }

    $newJsonString = json_encode($data);
    file_put_contents('status.json', $newJsonString);

    return true;
}
```

At first I thought it was a malfunction but the example below worked just fine

```
$.post( "test.php", function( data ) {
    alert(data);
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
echo "test";
```

Comment: Any errors/warnings from browser console?

Comment: return php statement wont work with ajax call, and once check alert in your written ajax call's response

Comment: define "doesnt work"

Answer (score 2):

In order to get data back into the Javascript ajax call, you need the php script to **echo** something.

Return values in php do not find their way back into the Ajax call.

Often, php scripts echo a value, either a single value or if you want the get more complex data from php back into the Ajax call, you can json encode several values and echo that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo/print something in php script to send response to ajax request. You have to do something like below.

```
$response=false;
if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if ($action) {
        $response=manageMaintenance($id, true);
    } else {
        $response=manageMaintenance($id, false);
    }
}

function manageMaintenance($room_id, $status)
{
    $jsonString = file_get_contents('status.json');
    $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    foreach ($data['rooms'] as $key => $entry) {
        if ($key == $room_id) {
            $data[$key]['maintenance'] = $status;
        }
    }

    $newJsonString = json_encode($data);
    file_put_contents('status.json', $newJsonString);

    return true;
}

echo $response==true? "OK" : "FAILED";
```